# When exactly is the "there is a teleporter" information said?

Tags: overwatch

I don't understand when exactly it is said, but it's pretty important information.

What exactly does it mean if a character says that the enemy team has a teleporter?

Comment: It will look like an orange oval with a platform if its enemy team, if you find an enemy teleporter, destroy it instantly. If it's blue, it's friendly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Overwatch Wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter) says that when **Symmetra  places it**, someone on the opposing team will announce its existence.  When someone on the enemy team actually **spots the teleporter**, they will announce that they have found it.

Comment: this is nothing new. I can certainly say that it is not jsut said if they see them. there are other keyfactors triggering it. And that is what made me ask.

Comment: @Zaibis I've revised my answer to clarify when someone says this.

Answer (score 5):

To slightly expand on the existing answers:
There are three different cases when a voice line is triggered regarding the enemy portal.

1. At the same instant she places in on the ground, someone on your team will say there's a portal.
2. When a friendly (or YOU) spots the portal. Now this is interesting because even your hero can announce that they've found the portal, even though it may not be in your line of sight. I've had many instances where my hero would say they've found the portal even though I haven't spotted it with my own eyes. I'd start spinning around looking for it to destroy it.
3. The last voice line would be triggered the moment a friendly destroys the portal.

Comment: To expand on 2., I'm fairly confident that your character can also say the teleporter found line if you see an enemy team member run into your line of sight with the recently teleported particles still on/around them.